# Is it possible to set IP restrictions for Windows Azure Web sites?

Tags: asp.net, security, web-applications, azure

We are using Windows Azure Web Sites, so we don't create Web roles. Now we need to temporarily set IP restrictions for the site, and I am not sure this is possible for Web Sites.

What is usually done is adding ipSecurity element to system.webServer section in web.config. But the ipSecurity section is locked by default, so it must be first unlocked by running a script command. But running Startup script is not possible for Azure Web sites, is it?

Does this mean that for Azure Web Sites (that don't have Web roles) it's simply not possible to configure IP range restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nir Mashkowski explains in a blog post on [how you can enable IP Restriction in Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/).

Comment: Updated the link to http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/08/27/configuring-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/ which is the new Azure Blog site.

Comment: and the link is dead again :(

Comment: New Link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ipSecurity is not active on Azure Web Sites.

Workaround: you can write a small piece of code in global.asax Application_BeginRequest and check the client ip address on your allowed IP addresses list. You can load the list on Application_Start.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(...)
{
  string clientIP = request.UserHostAddress;
  if (!Check(clientIP, myOKList))
  {
    Response.Write("<html><body>You are not authorized!</body></html>");
    Response.End();
  }
}
```